# Segmentation fault on malloc on one test case

Tags: c, debugging

Can any guru please assist me in identifying a segmentation fault? The segmentation fault seem to only be problematic on one of my test cases and appears to happen when allocating memory for a particular pointer within a struct. This works in all other test cases, which makes it kind of strange.

Here's my code:

http://pastebin.com/dfUqQnYy - the segmentation fault occurs at line 453.

```
speeches[i].who = malloc(nb_of_sirs_involved * sizeof(int));
```

Here are example inputs passed as arguments (using cat):

http://pastebin.com/YWv1F88G - the one causing the segmentation fault.

http://pastebin.com/i0V7KNH3 - one of the other test cases that do not cause segmentation fault.

I'm not sure what is wrong. What causes a malloc to fail? I'm sure I have enough memory to allocate!

Comment: I don't think it's malloc failing, it's more likely (although I've not read the code) that `speeches[i]` doesn't exist.

Comment: pastebin is not so good an idea. you should provide an http://sscce.org/

Comment: @Navnath - that won't prevent the segfault though...

Comment: you should check the result of malloc()! if you malloc/free many small and different sized chunks, you may get out of memory faster than you think

Comment: asking this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ may be more appropriate. at any rate, SO should not replace good old debugger.

Comment: I checked speeches[i] does exist... and I've debugged so many times. It just says segmentation fault... at the point where I'm meant to allocate the memory. It just won't let me allocate the memory without telling me why.

Comment: @mvp [codereview.se] is for working code only, debugging is off topic there.

Comment: What platform are you running on? I just tested your code and don't get any segfault...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found problem. It was a boolean variable which wasn't initialised... I don't know how it can be related to speeches[i].who but it fixed my problem. Thanks all.